# Combining field values with redux-form v6

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm migrating part of an application from `redux-form v5` to `v6` (`alpha-10`). I need to display the combined values of some fields.

In `v5`, I would have something like:

```
class MyForm extends Component {                            
  render() {                                                

    const { fields: { first, last }, handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (                                                
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                        

        <div>                                               
          <label>First name</label>
          <input type="text" {...first}/>
        </div>                                              

        <div>                                               
          <label>Last name</label>
          <input type="text" {...last}/>
        </div>

        <div>
          Welcome {first.value last.value.toUpperCase()}
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>               
      </form>                                               
    )
  }
}
```

The last `div` of the form combines the values of my two `first` and `last` fields. How can I create such an element with `v6` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just published an API for this exact thing. Check out the [Selecting Form Values](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.11/examples/selectingFormValues/) example.